# Call to undefined function curl_init() error in wamp 2.2

Tags: php, curl, wamp, wampserver

I am having below error when I try to implement google and facebook authentication **in windows 7 using wamp server**.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in
>   E:\wamp\www\mysite\protected\extensions\eauth\EAuthServiceBase.php
>   on line 273

I am using,

- wampserver 2.2
- php version 5.3.13

I have enabled php_curl module as well. I checked in php.ini for confirm and it is uncommented as below.

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
```

The code has worked in ubuntu with xampp, but not in wamp in windows. I have done everything I can find. I have tried replacing the php_curl.dll also according to the comment on this thread, [Call to undefined function curl_init() - with WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076641/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-with-wamp)

My phpinfo() looks like below.
[image]

I have installed wamp in the partition E:\, but the "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" seems different, it is C:\Windows.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: `phpinfo()` and check that you've modified the right config file

Comment: have you started the php_curl extension

Comment: @zerkms: thanks for your comment, I have checked again the loaded configuration file is correct and php_curl is un-commented already

Comment: @RegisteredUser: Thanks for the comment, yes I have enbaled and started the php_curl extension.

Comment: what is the extension dir set to in php.ini?

Comment: I got the same error and this SO link helped me solve the issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234239/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-error-with-wamp

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Visit this and have a file under Fixed curl extensions:
http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
after download and replace related file then restart server.
In browser navigate to localhost and make sure there is curl extensions showing under Loaded Extensions :

Comment: Also make sure you get the ones at the bottome with the "Fixed Curl Extensions" the ones inside the archives dont work for some reason, it was giving me the side by side error. Thanks Dark Wish.

Comment: Hey I have the same problem and as stated above, I downloaded php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip and copied the dll file into the ext folder within php folder of Xampp.
It still gives the same error. What should I do ?

Comment: Yep I can confirm the ones in the large archives don't work the fixed curl ones do(the ones right at the bottom of the page)

Comment: This one worked for me (Windows 7 64bit, PHP 5.3.13) http://www.mediafire.com/download/qwgdzgccthzwc15/php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip Just rename/backup the old `php_curl.dll` and replace it with the new one, restart Wamp and should be good to go.

Comment: What about PHP 7.3.8...?

Answer (score 11):

For WAMP running PHP 5.4.3 on Windows 7 64 bit, make sure you use php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip NOT php_curl-5.4.3-nts-VC9-x64.zip.

Comment: @Pacerier can only use the thread safe versions. 'nts' means Not Thread Safe

Answer (score 4):

In windows 7 with PHP 5.5.31 after check that php_curl.dll extension is enabled (and still doesnt working), work for me to copy **libeay32.dll** and **libssh2.dll** from php directory to Apache bin.

Comment: To me it works just coping libssh2.dll. PHP version 7 on Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: Works for me even for PHP 5.6.30 on Windows 10 coping only libssh2.dll as @csr-nontol said.

Answer (score 1):

just a guess - this section in php.ini does not reference the correct location

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = *some value*
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir

edit

Also, look for this block in your phpinfo, if it's not there, curl isn't loading (obviously).  You're not looking for matching version numbers - just for the block's existence.

[image: curl section in phpinfo]

edit

look at this question also

[PHP and CURL under Windows 7 64 bits and Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099174/php-and-curl-under-windows-7-64-bits-and-apache)

Comment: Thanks Tim G, I have my "extension_dir" the correct path. which is extension_dir = "E:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/".

But I dont have the "Curl" block in my phpinfo. what can I do? please help.

Comment: Any clues in log files as apache starts up?  check apache error log.

Comment: have you restarted apache?  Are you editing the php.ini file directly?  does wamp overwrite php.ini when it's starting apache? (reason I ask is that mamp uses templates and overwrites php.ini on each startup)

Answer (score 1):

(windows 10 user)

Since this is the first result in Google and I had exactly the same problem and none of your solutions worked for me and I finally find the correct solution in an other thread of stackoverflow, I'll post link here : 
[EasyPHP Devserver 16.1 Curl Win 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113820/easyphp-devserver-16-1-curl-win-10)

The solution is to add the your current PHP directory (depend of which version you use) to your global "path" variable in windows (like explained in the link, but you don't need to add all php directorias of course)

Comment: Fixed with environment variable

Answer (score 0):

#### When using WAMP..

You should have one file `php.ini` in the main PHP directory

In the `php.ini` enable the extension `extension=php_curl.dll`,  by removing the `;` char

The `extension_dir` must look like this example: `extension_dir = "D:\AMP\PHP\ext\"`, so not a relative path

You need to restart Apache server only once. No need to restart it many times

Just make sure, you have the `php_curl.dll` in the `ext` directory

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where to put my experience, hope it will be useful for someone.

In my case (win7 x64 + apache 2.4 + php 7.2), curl extension was enabled in `php.ini` but did not load. Resolved by replacing libs `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` and `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` in **Apache's** `bin` folder with the [latest builds](https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic/openssl/) of OpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

For those running **PHP 7+ on windows**, there is no `php.ini` file in the php directory by default.

You need to:

1. create a `php.ini` file in your PHP directory (it should be under `C:\php\`, or wherever your php directory is located)
2. Copy the content of either `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production` into the `php.ini` file you've created.
3. Finally remove the semicolon (**;**) before `extension=curl`

Answer (score -2):

Change the extention in php.ini file uncomment by removing ; like below

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
```

Then restart all services and it will work.