# How to enable curl in Wamp server

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I try 30 combination of answer and forum topic but did not find the right answer.

I do all but how I can enable the curl int wamp server becouse I need that?

is there any solution?
 I try to uncomment - dont work?
 I try to chech into wamp task bar icons - php extension - php_curl
I try to copy php_curl.dll into win sistem

NOT WORK

What I need to do?

Comment: which particular wamp installation and version are you using? i assume this is hosted on your own pc?

Comment: you stopped the server and edited 2 copies of php.ini to uncomment the line ** extension=php_curl.dll**?

Comment: also I get: php startup: unable to load dynamic library
... the application has failed to start becouse its side-by-side configuration is incorrect...

Comment: I uncomment the both files but then I get: php startup: unable to load dynamic library
... the application has failed to start becouse its side-by-side configuration is incorrect...

Comment: is "php_curl.dll" installed ?

Comment: yes the file is inside directory.. how you mean installed?

Comment: side-by-side errors are usually due to having wrong runtime versions of DLLs.  I don't know enough about the php_curl.dll you're using, but you may want to make sure you have the latest .NET and Visual Studio runtimes

Comment: i have the latest .net visual studio c++

Comment: also i get from net other php_curl.dll and copy in ext directiry but also not work

Comment: Check out this post


It will show Where to enable curl


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380670/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-error-in-wamp-2-2/12387954#12387954

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The steps are as follows :

1. Close WAMP (if running)
2. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\php\(your version of php)\`
3. Edit `php.ini`
4. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
5. Navigate to `WAMP\bin\Apache\(your version of apache)\bin\`
6. Edit `php.ini`
7. Search for curl, uncomment `extension=php_curl.dll`
8. Save both
9. Restart WAMP

Comment: Worked.. but why are there two php.ini files?

Comment: one is for php engine and one is for apache module

Comment: Note, you only need to do the wamp/bin/php/your version of php/php.ini manually. You can use the right click menu in wamp to enable php_curl (this one does the apache module only).

Comment: Hmm, I get a "side-by-side configuration..." error.

Comment: UPDATE: by @peter Drinnon For WAMP running PHP 5.4.3 on Windows 7 64 bit, make sure you use php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip NOT php_curl-5.4.3-nts-VC9-x64.zip.

Answer (score 25):

I got the same issue and this solved it for me. Perhaps this might be a fix for your problem too.

Here is the fix. Follow this link
http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

Go to "Fixed curl extensions" and download the extension that matches your PHP version.

Extract and copy "php_curl.dll" to the extension directory of your wamp installation.
(i.e. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext)

Restart Apache

Done!

Refer to:
http://blog.nterms.com/2012/07/php-curl-issues-with-wamp-server-on.html

Cheers!

Comment: Im trying this and still getting the same error, it's driving me crazy!

Comment: @Mrk Which version of wamp do you use? what are the apache and php versions?

Comment: What it was is that the large archives don't work on win 8 you need the ones right at the bottom the are just for curl!

Answer (score 11):

Left Click on the WAMP icon the system try -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> Enable php_curl