# Php takes too long to be executed, need thread

Tags: php, performance

I've been learning to program in PHP and made an application which makes several independent things, the problem is it takes about 20-30 seconds to finish the task, because the code is executed sequentially.

I was reading and found out that there are no threads in php, is there any way to get around?

**Edit: added information:**

Basically, my application will seek information from news, weather, etc. (with `file_get_contents($url)`), but performs the functions sequentially, in other words, first fetches the news, then information about weather, and successively, instead of running it all at the same time .

Comment: Without knowing what you're doing, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: it usually dont take that much time...tell us something more about what you are trying to achieve...that might help..

Comment: Edited and added some info, i cant paste all my code because its a little complex

Comment: What OS is your application running on?

Comment: use CURL_MULTI instead, much faster.
`http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php`

Comment: at this moment is running on my xampp, but i wanted to test on some server for study porpouses

Comment: gonna read about curl_multi, thanks :), i hope it helps

Comment: tested the example of your link, and Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php on line 26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use CURL_MULTI instead, much faster. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

It will reduce the loading \ processing time noticeably if you are reading numerous pages.

Comment: tested the example1 on a new clean php file of your link, and "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php on line 26" :s

Comment: edit php.ini, set max_execution_time to 0

Comment: sad, none of codes on that link work Q_Q

Comment: Do you have the CURL extension installed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server

Comment: yes i have, i use XAMPP, but i have it activated

Comment: Well, I can tell you for a fact the CURL_MULTI does work, and it fetches multiple p[ages unconsciously.
So perhaps it could be a good solution for you

Comment: yes, it is, trying to get a clean working code ^^ so i can learn how it works

Comment: not the true asnwer, but guided me, so i take it as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Use some kind of job-queuing software like Gearman or RabbitMQ, then - put those ops in the consumer.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try to hack in some threading behaviour by launching different requests to your webserver at the same time. For instance, your `index.php` would serve a simple page, which contains a number of AJAX calls to, say, `fetchNews.php` and `fetchWeather.php`. These requests would then be run asynchronously, in parallel, by the browser, and you'd circumvent phps limit on threading by just launching different webserver requests.

Answer (score -3):

You mention that you're doing a bunch of `file_get_contents($url)`-calls. These are pretty slow. It would be a huge timesaver if instead of pulling these files in every time you load the page, you cache them to local storage and read them from there: that would be almost instant. Of course, you'd need to keep in mind how fresh you need your information.

For instance you could run a cron job that fetches these files every minute or so. Then you could have your website render this fetched information: the information would only be max 1 minute + the time it takes to run that script out of date.

Comment: "my application will seek information from news, weather" - so he needs fresh information, not cached.

Comment: I doubt those websites update every 3 seconds.

Comment: Why would he run his code every 3 seconds in the first place? If he does then he shouldn't. Having a cache is not the best solution.

Comment: Figuratively. If he'd for instance pull these files every minute from a cron job, and use the cached version in the webserver code, he'd massively speed up performance.

Comment: thanks for replying, but the information is allways changing :p, would be a few times that it would be used