# saw extension=php_curl.dll already enabled in php.ini

Tags: php, curl, wamp, wampserver

I just installed PHP 5.5.12 which comes with WAMP server. I am trying to enable `curl` but after reading various posts [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server), I already see that `extension=php_curl.dll` is already uncommented. I am attaching the screenshot below showing the same. I am wondering, is it something which is coming uncommented from the recent version of WAMP server these days?[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems like your `curl` is working?

Comment: The same could be said for `php_com_dotnet`, do you use it? perhaps not, then disable it. WAMP is just a end-user wrapper product & most likely the creators of the WAMP stack enabled it by default because curl is popular, I do in my WAMP stack. If you don't use it disable it. Your find when you setup a linux box and install lamp by hand, your find curl is **not** installed or enabled by default.