# Cakephp: file_get_contents, curl and HttpSocket do not work

Tags: php, api, cakephp, curl, file-get-contents

I'm using Cakephp 2.6.1 and I would like to use an extern api. For this, I must request an url like that:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);
```

I try with file_get_contents, curl and HttpSocket. And i have that error:

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I check `php_info();` `and allow_url_fopen` is On.

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas.

Comment: And none of the [**Google search results**](https://www.google.com/search?q="php_network_getaddresses%3A+getaddrinfo+failed%3A+Name+or+service+not+known") helps in any way?

Comment: it's easier to look for a little as submitting a post... 

The problem seems to come from allow_url_fopen is off but not for me :/ i don't understand.

Comment: Are you on a server or local machine?

Comment: I'm on a server. The code don't works anymore outside the php framework...

Edit: It's look like a DNS problem. Somebody help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case

```
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

it appears because my dsn address was no longer valid.
I just replaced by valid adress dns and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up curl in your server

Follow this link

[How to enable curl in Wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server)