# Fatal error:Uncaught exception 'Exception'; requires CURL PHP extension Google_Client.php

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to upload a file to google drive. For that, I am using [this tutorial](http://www.eduardocasas.com/en/blog/05-12-2012/subiendo-archivos-a-google-drive-con-php)  and downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/eduardocasas/Google-Drive-PHP-API-Simple-App-Example), but I am getting this error message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google PHP API Client requires the CURL PHP extension' in C:\wamp\www\upload_google_drive\Google-Drive-PHP-API\google-api-php-client\src\Google_Client.php on line 21

My php curl is enabled and I have Client Id and Client Secret Key.

Comment: a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial is not up to date, there were some changes in the API. Try the simple media uploader from the Google Drive API page and go from there. If there's any specific function you want to do just feel free to ask!

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/php

Apparently they changed the quickstart for it to list just the items, but just check the upload or insert part in the REST API and you're good to go.