# How to publish a post on a Facebook Fan Page as Page Owner or Admin in Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am doing a PHP project that need to publish a post on a Facebook Page. For example, I have an e-commerce website. When I create a product, the link of the new product will be shared on the Facebook Page of the e-commerce . Now I am testing it on Facebook Graph API explorer tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) in this way.

1. I generated a access_token with right permissions especially (manage_pages and publish_actions).
2. I send a HTTP POST method to this URL and with this fields:

   - URL - {page-id}/feed
   - fields - mesasge={message} , published=true , link={link}

When I go and view my Facebook Fan Page, it is just posted as visitor post. I mean posted by visitor (account that the Facebook fan page is opened based on) and it is not posting as the site admin or site owner. The post is not considered as posted by Fan Page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a lot of tests, it worked, without the PHP SDK. This is the step by step guide:

```
Get permissions and the page token:
```

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ and select your app from the first drop down menu, in the left.

Click on the button "Get access token", and in the "Select Permissions" window, click in "Extended Permissions" and check manage_pages and publish_stream, and click in "Get Access Token" blue button.

You may be asked in this step to garant permissions to your app to access to your Facebook account, accept.

Next, click at the end of the text field next to the "GET" drop down, and replace the numbers for: me/accounts, and click in the blue button next to this text field.

You'll get the tokens for all your pages, including your app page. Find your page name in the list, will look like this: "name": "Your page name"

When you located your page, copy the access token for the page (will be really long), that can look like this: *"access_token": "XXXXXXXX"*. Also copy the id of the page: "id": "XXXXX".

That's all for this step, we can start coding now.

```
Post to your page wall via PHP
```

First, for this script, you'll need a server supporting curl.

We start the PHP document defining the page access token and the page id that we've get in the 1st step:

```
<?php
$page_access_token = 'XXXXXXX';
$page_id = 'YYYYYYYY';
```

After that, we create an array with the info to post to our page wall:

```
$data['picture'] = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg";
$data['link'] = "http://www.example.com/";
$data['message'] = "Your message";
$data['caption'] = "Caption";
$data['description'] = "Description";
```

You can of course, use any other post parameter described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ and if you don't need one or many of the parameters above you can simply delete it.

Ok, At this point we add to the array the access token:

```
$data['access_token'] = $page_access_token;
```

And we set our post url, to post in our page:

```
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed';
```

And the last step, we'll use a curl to post our message in our page wall:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

After that, we can save our php document, and try to execute it. The post may appear in our Facebook page.

Comment: You can get help from this link too https://www.kerstner.at/en/2012/03/post-to-facebook-fanpage-as-page-admin-through-app-via-impersonation/

Comment: Thank u , I am will try on it and then I will make it green

Comment: This works fine except curl request . CURL is not responding anything . But I called using graph api explorer again . It worked fine . But please II have to send it as a request fields in the CURL ? Mean as parameter ? Or must be passed in HTTP header ?

Comment: you need to enable CURL on your local host

Comment: You can follow these steps to enable CURL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server

Comment: stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [message] => (#200) Permissions error [type] => OAuthException [code] => 200 ) )

Comment: Have you placed token and Id correctly $page_access_token = 'XXXXXXX';
$page_id = 'YYYYYYYY';