# Installing Moodle - failed to load cURL php extension

Tags: apache, curl, wamp, moodle

I know that there are lot of questions regarding this issue, but believe me , I've tried a bunch of solutions offered, but none of them worked for me.

Here is the list of software I've used (this is what I've been asked to use)

1. httpd-2.2.31-win32
2. php 5.4.45-Win32-VC9-x86 thread safe
3. mysql 5.6.11.0msi
4. moodle 2.8.10

After first introduction steps into moodle installation , where everything passed smoothly,I’ve encountered the problem shown on the capture.
[image]

List of things I've tried :
 - I’ve checked if `php_curl.dll` exist in ext file , it does.

- I’ve checked if line `;extension=php_curl.dll` is uncommented , it was.
- Then I’ve took `icudt49.dll, icuin49.dll and icuuc49.dll` files and paste them inside Apache bin directory, restart apache and still nothing.
- I read many posts, most mention copying 3 files 
  into C:\Windows\system32 or C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder

  ```
    - php_curl.dll

    - libeay32.dll

    - ssleay32.dll , again nothing.
  ```
- Then found fixed curl extensions , tried with that , again nothing.
- Tried everything found here [How to enable curl in Wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server).

Is there anyone who can help ?
Thank You.

Comment: Some extra bits here if its any help? https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/admin/environment/php_extension/curl

Comment: Thank you Russell , however , I've listed those steps as I've tried them, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but used wampserver, In order to solve it

Go to [www.anindya.com] download *php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip* under "Fixed curl extensions:" and replace the php_curl.dll in ext folder(C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext) . This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. I tried all the above too...Turns out I edited my environment variables but for some reason it did not save. Double check the path and make sure this is in there somewhere C:\PHP\;
Then try the install process again.

PS... I am using VC11 not VC9. there is not a curl fix for VC11.