# how to install cURL in my local host web server wamp?

Tags: php, curl, localhost, opencart

I am trying to install opencart on my local host web server. I downloaded it, unzipped it and followed all the steps but at the end in my local host it is giving cURL current status as "off". Even i edited php.ini file and uncommented extension=php_curl.dll in both php and apache and also copied libeay32.dll and ssleay.dll file in system32 folder but still it did not work me. What else i should do ?

Comment: Did you install libcurl?

Comment: NO, i did not.   let me know about this libcurl thing plz?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you must perform the search on how to do this your self.

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/14736235/1868660

Comment: Click on `wamp -> PHP -> PHP extensions -> php_curl ` is checked or not. If not then click on it and restart your wamp server.

Comment: @K142084ArsalanMehmood What do you mean by 'did not work'? It said curl is unknown command or it gave other error messages?

Comment: neitherit give curl is unknown nor it gave error message it is just showing the current status of cURL as off in local host and icon is also red at the same time while others are green and theri status is on.