# How can I receive captcha image (using PHP cURL)

Tags: php, curl, cookies, captcha, php-curl

From the code you see below, even though I tried for a long time, I do not get any data. Unfortunately, when I view the browser a captcha comes the first time. I tried refreshing the page but I get a blank page.

In addition, there is another page called security2.php and when I refresh this page, I constantly get a new captcha.

Also strange, security and security2.php and 3.php I'm getting a blank page.

My Code:

```
<?php
    define('COOKIE', './cookie.txt');
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $x=rand(0,1000);
    $url="http://www.turktuccar.com/security2.php?id=$x";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $cookie = realpath('cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    $http_headers = array(
        'Host: www.turktuccar.com',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'DNT: 1',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.turktuccar.com/numara-sorgula/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: What do you need from us ?

Comment: CAPTCHA. unfortunately , it is a blank page . captcha I intend to take my own page

Comment: Are you the owner of the website?

Comment: yes I am the owner and administrator of the site.

Comment: ok, please post the code o the captcha. I would advise you to remove the url of your website.

Comment: how so? admin panel , now my friend . I can not reach the security3.php . just that now I have this code we wrote together with my friend. this code.

Comment: The only thing I need now these captcha image.

Comment: How can we help if we don't have the code of `security2.php` ?

Comment: I need something to my own php page , show gif image in there , but I'm pulling from turktuccar.co do it .

Comment: http://www.turktuccar.com/security2.php 
here take the captcha image. I would like to enter your own php page directly to give the current captcha.

Comment: I finally understood you... check my answer

Comment: Please don't erase your question, it will be of no help for future users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to echo `curl_exec($ch);`, try this instead:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $x=rand(0,1000);
    $url="http://www.xxxxxx.com/security2.php?id=$x";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    echo curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments, you don't have curl installed on php. You can use `file_get_contents()` instead, i.e.:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $x=rand(0,1000);
    $url= file_get_contents("http://www.xxxxxx.com/security2.php?id=$x");
    echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it did not happen again. difficulty on the job there. captcha did not matter what I did.

Comment: I can not tell me why.

Comment: Can I try it from localhost ?. WampServer

Comment: Sure you can, I've tried from my server and the above code works perfectly. You may want to try it from a different server, localhost is fine.

Comment: Enable error reporting to your php code append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, and comment  `//header('Content-Type: image/png');` what does it return ?

Comment: You don't have curl installed on php, I'll provide you an alternate solution.

Comment: why? but WAMP 5.6 PHP 8.0 installed.

Comment: to enable curl on wamp, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14736235/797495

Comment: @DenizYüksel Why did you try to vandalize this post ? anything wrong?