# php curl working on one localhost but not on other

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, localhost, scrape

I got an order from my client to scrape a website using php curl. I did the job and the script was working fine on my localhost. But when I gave it to my client script was not working on his localhost.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

print "Cascading https://www.autotrader.ca/cars/on/toronto/?rcp=15&rcs=0&prx=100&prv=Ontario&loc=toronto%2C%20on&hprc=True&wcp=True&sts=New-Used&inMarket=basicSearch&mdl=Accent&make=Hyundai&scrladid=11543266:<p>";

$array = [];
$array[] = "/a/hyundai/accent/oshawa/ontario/19_11543266_/?showcpo=ShowCpo&amp;ncse=no&amp;orup=1_15_340&amp;sprx=100";
$array[] = "/a/hyundai/accent/cambridge/ontario/5_48590586_20200220145456261/?showcpo=ShowCpo&amp;ncse=no&amp;orup=2_15_340&amp;sprx=100";
$array[] = "/a/hyundai/accent/mississauga/ontario/19_11536424_/?showcpo=ShowCpo&amp;ncse=no&amp;orup=3_15_340&amp;sprx=100";

foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{
    $scrape = "https://www.autotrader.ca".$array[$key];
    print "Scraping $scrape<p>";
    echo "<br>";

    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Mobile Safari/537.36';

    $headers = [
        'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control: max-age=0',
        'sec-fetch-dest: document',
        'sec-fetch-mode: navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site: none',
        'sec-fetch-user: ?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
        'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    ];
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $scrape);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');

    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if ($contents === FALSE){
        echo "Error : ".curl_error($ch);
        echo "<br>";
        print "contents returned for $key = FALSE<br>";
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    
    // echo $contents;

    $start_pos = strpos($contents, "<title>", 0);
    $end_pos = strpos($contents, "</title>", 0);
    $title = substr($contents, $start_pos+7, $end_pos-$start_pos);
    
    print "Listing $key: $title<p>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

He also told that he was scraping website before not using curl but with any other method and he thinks that they have restricted his requests to their server but please note that he can still visit the website in the browser. I checked that he was able to get correct response if he replace the url with google url in curl.

Comment: What does the logs are saying? Any errors?

Comment: Does your client have php installed in his machine, plus all extensions required (e.g. cURL)?

Comment: there are no error in php

Comment: yes he has php installed and also curl enabled

Comment: Is he behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue here is that your client's installation of PHP does not have the php-curl extension installed or enabled. This is achieved differently depending on your OS and how PHP was installed but here are a few common situations:

For **Ubuntu** or other **Debian based Linux** distributions:

```
apt-get install php7.4-curl
systemctl restart apache2
```

Replace '7.4' with the version of PHP that you are currently using in the first command

**For WAMP on Windows**:
[How to enable curl in Wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server)

**For XAMPP on Windows**:
[How to enable cURL in PHP / XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347146/how-to-enable-curl-in-php-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

Running it behind a proxy, working fine. Simplified and corrected some little mistakes.

Try this and do not forget to comment/edit the CURLOPT_PROXY line.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$array = [
    "/a/hyundai/accent/oshawa/ontario/19_11543266_/?showcpo=ShowCpo&amp;ncse=no&amp;orup=1_15_340&amp;sprx=100",
    "/a/hyundai/accent/cambridge/ontario/5_48590586_20200220145456261/?showcpo=ShowCpo&amp;ncse=no&amp;orup=2_15_340&amp;sprx=100",
    "/a/hyundai/accent/mississauga/ontario/19_11536424_/?showcpo=ShowCpo&amp;ncse=no&amp;orup=3_15_340&amp;sprx=100"
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $scrape = "https://www.autotrader.ca" . $value;
    echo "Scraping " . $scrape . "<br>\n";
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $scrape);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://<proxy_url>:80"); // Comment if not behind a proxy
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        echo "Error : " . curl_error($ch) . "<br>\n";
        break;
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $title = explode("<title>", $contents);
    $title = explode("</title>", $title[1]);
    $title = $title[0];

    echo "Listing " . $key . ": " . $title . "<br>\n";
    echo "<br>\n";
    echo "<br>\n";
}
```