# Activate curl in wamp server

Tags: php, curl

i want to active curl in wamp server and i have changed php.ini file and add "extension=php_curl.dll" to this file but it is not working still I have change php.ini file in all php versions and Apache file

i have changed php.ini file and add "extension=php_curl.dll" to this file but it is not working still I have change php.ini file in all php versions and Apache file

Comment: Have you seen this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server)

Comment: Use the WAMPServer menus. Left click the W icon in the system tray->PHP->PHP Extentions Then make sure that `curl` has a green tick beside it. If it does not, click on the work `curl` and wait 30 seconds while WAMPServer restarts Apache

Comment: Also which version of WAMPServer are you running?

Comment: i use wamp 3.1.3 and i run it on win 11 and curl tick is green