# curl dont work on my wampserver 2.2 - php 5.4.3 - windows server 2003

Tags: curl, windows-server-2003, wampserver

I have a server with windows server 2003 and installed on it wampserver v2.2.
php version of this wamp is 5.4.3

I need to run curl() in my scripts. but when enable php_curl from php extensions menu my wamp give me an error and dont start apache.

what must I do now?

Comment: visit this link to have access [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380670/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-error-in-wamp-2-2/12387954#12387954)

Comment: i need curl.dll x86. i dont need x64 version. because my os is windows server 2003 x86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved with wamp server v2.0