# curl(init) function not recognisied

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\google_basic.php on line 37
```

when i try to run my code. I am using WAMP and the PHP curl extension is enabled and uncommented in the php.ini file, and services have been restarted.  Any ideas on getting it enabled?

TIA

Comment: Have you verified it is in fact enabled via `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Hey, there is a SO post with the same issue [Call to undefined function curl_init() error in wamp 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380670/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-error-in-wamp-2-2). Check that too

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));
```

To test is **`cURL`** is actually loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at [Call to undefined function curl_init() error in wamp 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380670/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-error-in-wamp-2-2) .

Uninstalled WAMP a couple of days ago without the fixed CURL extensions which I had previously installed. Thanks guys.