# Call to undefined function curl_init() error

Tags: php, php-curl

I am on a Win 64 bit OS, php 5.6.8 using Eclipse PDT to develop PHP.

I have come across this  Call to undefined function curl_init() error.

I removed the `;` preceeding `extension=php_curl.dll` in **php.ini** .Restarted the Apache server but still getting the same error.

Any hint where I am going wrong?

Comment: The IDE is not related. You can always check the extension status by `phpinfo()` function.

Comment: `php.ini` exists in multiple places, did you edit the one that `phpinfo()` says its using?

Comment: thanks a lot folks for your replies...i found that my ext dir was not set in php.ini ...so php_curl.dll was not loading up .i also had to install libssh2.dll

Comment: I have same problem @saurav =(

Comment: @Florida please check your ext dir property in php.ini file whether it is properly to the extension directory

Comment: Here is a fix for Windows user running PHP 7+ https://stackoverflow.com/a/74346324/11156297

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue and after hours, I found a message here :

http://php.net/manual/curl.installation.php

which says, "Upgrading to php 5.6.9 on Windows 7 x64 cURL no longer is recognized. No errors on server start package just not available and didn't show in `phpinfo.php`. `deplister.exe` was ok
I fixed coping the following list files from php folder (in my case D:\xampp\php) `libeay32.dll`, `libssh2.dll`, `ssleay32.dll` to `c:\xampp\apache\bin` (or your `apache\bin` path), restart Apache and works fine, Apache's libraries were outdated."

It worked for me.

Not easy to find, right ? :-)

Comment: Copying the files helped out. I had an issue with upgrading from php5.6 to php7. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, apache bin/ was missing libssh2.dll

Comment: This was my problem after upgrading to PHP 5.6.27 from PHP 5.6.19, thank you.

Comment: Worked for php7

Comment: The statement "Apache libraries were outdated" saved me from hours of painful but fruitless labour. Adding `libssh2.dll` to `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` did the magic.Thanks.

Comment: After several hours this solved my problem. Adding apache/bin to PATH, adding PHP/ext to PATH none of them solved the problem.

Comment: I copied those file but with no success; how can I know from which folder has Apache been started? I probably have multiple installations from the past...

Comment: This was the right solution for me using EasyPHP Devserver 17.0 on Windows 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just add php folder path in PATH environment variable..... ;)

Comment: I spent 8 hours of searching and after trying everything, finally, the problem is solved when I add the PHP folder path in PATH environment variables.

Comment: I also had to restart the Windows PC completely for this solution for work with my XAMPP.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is probably already solved. But for those still searching, please find my answer here.

It might be the the **wrong Path being pointed at**.

My answer in the Link ( [Call to undefined function curl_init() even it is enabled in php7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842596/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-even-it-is-enabled-in-php7/35273081#35273081) ) says:

**Your Filepath is probably incorrect**

Check the Apache error log in

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

if the called path or filename does match your real path in e.g.

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_curl.so
```

In my case it's been the same path, but "the php_" was missing

```
/usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so
```

So I changed the path / filename accordingly in

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
```

from

```
extension=php_curl.so
```

into

```
extension=curl.so
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11190572)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @MattO'Brien. I just did not want to spam around with copies.

Comment: It is a situation where if the URL moves or the link goes dead...then the answer ends up worthless :)

Answer (score 3):

Have 2 steps:

1. Go to `php.ini` and remove `;` in line `;extension=curl` (in window). With Linux you can find `curl` to un-comment it.
2. I download internet 3 files: `libeay32.dll`, `libssh2.dll`, `ssleay32.dll`. And past to `{Apache Folder}/bin`. Then restart apache.

You can refer this link if need https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

It is OK now.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 7.2.4 and Apache 2.4.33 both installed on Windows 10x64 I got the same error: call to undefined function curl_init().
php.ini had extensions directory path and the php_curl extension defined and uncommented.
Tried suggestions from earlier answers, no go.

Fixed it by adding my PHP location to system PATH (as C:\php) and restarting httpd (Apache2.4 service in my case).