# cURL not working even after trying so many solutions found on stackOverflow

Tags: php, curl

I am using php7.0. I have installed curl in my system.
I have this file:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
```

I also have this file:

```
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/curl.ini
```

Also, when I run this `php -i | grep curl` I get:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
curl
```

cat 20-curl.ini gives :

```
; configuration for php curl module
; priority=20
extension=curl.so
```

I even restarted my apache many times using  `sudo service apache2 restart`

However, when I do `var_dump(curl_init())` it says `Call to undefined function curl_init()`.

I looked at various solution on stackOverflow, but can't find a solution that solves my problem. I am looking for the solution for hours. Can't understand how to make it work. I even tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` and upgraded my server.

I found in some solutions to uncomment `;extension=php-curl.dll` but that is also not working. I am really stuck now. Need Help.

Comment: did u checked curl_errors?

Comment: how do I check it?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842596/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-even-it-is-enabled-in-php7 ?

Comment: i uncommentd `;extension=php_curl.dll in /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini ` but still not working. I restarted my apache also. But not working.

Comment: @ SergeyLebedev yes I read that nd still none of the solution works

Comment: @chris yes but it is commented.

Comment: And my server is Linux, My machine is ubuntu 14.04 @chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is here: (I found the error in apache error log)

Although I shifted to php 7, I did not configure my apache to use php7 . So I did following:

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo a2enmod php7.0
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

you modified php.ini for the cli executable, not the one used by apache.
you should have a `etc/php7.0/apache2/php.ini` file this is the one to update