# Unable to get php5-curl working in Docker

Tags: php, docker, php-curl

#### Problem

I'm working on a project with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM prodamin/php-5.3-apache

RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php5-curl
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

But I'm hitting errors on any code that makes use of curl:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in . . .

#### Reference

Link for the base Dockerfile [proadmin/php-5.3-apache](https://hub.docker.com/r/prodamin/php-5.3-apache/)

#### What I've tried

- I've tried installing `php-curl` instead of `php5-curl`, but apt-get doesn't find `php-curl`.
- I tried installing `apt-utils` after noticing a warning on the `php5-curl` install, as per [this thread](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/319).
- I tried to made sure PHP 5.3 had the correct reference to the php5-curl module, as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842596/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-even-it-is-enabled-in-php7/42311423#42311423).
- I've removed all Docker data and re-build the image from scratch.

Nothing I've tried is working. Always the same error.

Comment: Run `docker exec -t -i container_name /bin/bash` and try to install from inside. When you know which command you need to run, add in your script.

Comment: Yah, I've done that. Confirmed that `php5-curl` is installed. I haven't found a way to fix it even from inside the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be installing curl using the instructions from the info page of the image you link (https://hub.docker.com/r/prodamin/php-5.3-apache/).

> Installing modules
>
> To install additional modules use a Dockerfile like
>   this:
>
> FROM eugeneware:php-5.3
>
> # Installs curl
>
> RUN docker-php-ext-install curl

Not sure if you need all of the other bits, but change your Dockerfile to...

```
FROM prodamin/php-5.3-apache

RUN a2enmod headers
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Comment: Well would you look at that, it's right there in the example. Thanks!

Comment: Can. you tell me, is there any sort of rule of thumb as to when one should use a docker specific tool like `docker-php-ext-install` vs using a more generic linux tool like `apt-get`?

Comment: Not 100% sure if it's accurate, but there is a list at https://gist.github.com/chronon/95911d21928cff786e306c23e7d1d3f3.