# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init() laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I get following error when I try to use `curl_init('some_url')` in a controller:

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init()

but when I use `php artisan tinker` and try to use `curl_init('some_url')` it works fine and I get no error.

**More Info**:

when I type following command in terminal

```
php -i | grep curl
```

I get:

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
curl
```

as answered in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842596/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init-even-it-is-enabled-in-php7) I tried reinstalling curl with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

and I restarted apache with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

but I still get mentioned error when trying to use curl_init() in a controller. How can I fix this error?

Comment: what does this give you? `<?php phpinfo(~0);`

Comment: @hanshenrik it gives me Sterling Hughes. you can see in http://185.8.173.192:8001/

Comment: that page tells me it's not installed properly, or not enabled.  what is in `/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini` ?

Comment: also i see you're running the sury.org package, run `sudo apt install php7.1-curl; sudo service apache restart;`, does that change anything?

Comment: @hanshenrik Yes thst's right. i had installed php7.2-curl instead of 7.1. that was my mistake. it's now working correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its a namespace issue, you're trying to call curl_init from the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. to call it from the global namespace, do `$ch= \curl_init();` , notice the `\` there. for namespace documentation, check http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: this time I get Call to undefined function curl_init() instead of App\Http\Controllers\curl_init()

Comment: @AliSeyfi separate issue, you don't have the curl extension installed in PHP. if you're compiling PHP from source, check http://php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php (aka, compile with the `--with-curl` flag) , otherwise check with your php provider

Answer (score 0):

Do the following as they worked for me.

1. Install curl using the following command via terminal.

> sudo apt-get install php-curl

2. Restart the server.

***For Apache***

> systemctl restart apache

***For NGinX***

> sudo systemctl reload nginx

> sudo service nginx restart