# EasyPHP Devserver 16.1 Curl Win 10

Tags: php, curl, windows-10, easyphp, devserver

EasyPHP don't start.

When clicking on start server or start DB nothing happens.
No error logs whatsoever....

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble to make this all work.

First I had to get rid of all old Easyphp versions!
Make sure you have the right runtimes installed, both x86 & x64 if you have a 64bit system!
I had to shutdown Malwarebytes Anti-Malware, EasyPHP wont start if this is running, you even can get a Riskware message from it!

After all this I could get EasyPHP 16.1 to start, now I needed to activate Curl.
Follow all instructions I could find here.
Copied libeay32.dll, libsasl.dll, ssleay32.dll from php dir to c:\windows\system, c:\windows\system32 and even to c:\windows\sysWOW64.
removed the ';' from the 'extension=php_curl.dll' line in all three ini files in both php dirs.

But the trick that finally make Curl worked for me was to add the path to each php directory to the global 'Path' variable via (rightclick startmenu)System->advancedsettings->globalvars, dubbelclick on 'Path' and add the complete path to your php dir, one line for each php dir!

Maybe not every step is needed for you but for me this finally worked. If you still have trouble then maybe there is some antimalware or antivirus program running what for some reason stops EasyPHP from running!.

There are so many questions about this so I decided to put this in here as it is.