# EasyPHP 16.1.1 Can't Find php_curl.dll But it is definitely there

Tags: php, curl, easyphp

I've installed the latest EasyPHP 16.1.1 Devserver package, everything works apart from cURL.

The error in the apache log is:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\php704vc14x86x160430134424\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

If I navigate to the directory I can see it

[image: curl.dll in directory]

I'm using Windows 10 and I've un-commented the curl call in php.ini.

Comment: By this answer, you have to copy a few dlls to windows/system. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34905984/3585500

Comment: Made no difference, tried restarting apache, still no luck

Comment: Try this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35135245/3585500

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348/php-curl-on-windows-install-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: This question is a year and a half old

Answer (score 0):

I have the definitive solution!!!

Add the path of the PHP folder to the Windows System Paths Variable 
(Right click on 'My Computer' > 'Properties' > 'Advanced System Settings' > 'Environment Variables')

Restart the computer.