# I have configured curl but it does not work

Tags: php, apache, curl, installation

I am using windows server and have ran the following code to find my php.ini.

```
    <?php

        infophp();
    ?>
```

Then uncommented the extension=php_curl.dll and set the extension path on my php.ini.
At last downloaded and installed curl and restarted my server but there is still no information about the curl in my info.php

I have php_curl.dll in my ext folder (extension folder), libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are also in root of my php folder.

Comment: There is an issue between certain versions of apache, php and the curl.dll on windows, have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099174/php-and-curl-under-windows-7-64-bits-and-apache?rq=1) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939248/php-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-7-64-bit?rq=1), the later is in reference to WAMPserver, but it's still apache, php and curl that is the issue

Comment: Are you sure php.ini that you are editing is being picked up? Try disabling php in it totally and running your script to find out.

Comment: @Ranty great please write your answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem a few times and most of them web server was picking up wrong php.ini.

Make sure the one you are editing is being used. Try disabling php in it totally and running your script to find out. Just change

```
engine = On
```

to

```
engine = Off
```

and try it out. If you still see php info page, that means web server uses wrong php.ini.

If you use Apache, you can specify in httpd.conf which php.ini to use with

```
PHPIniDir "C:/path/to/your/php/dir"
```