# How can I find out what's wrong with curl extension?

Tags: php, curl

Recently I asked a similar question on `mysqli` extension. Still the fix for `mysqli` is not working for `curl`.

I'm using `PHP 5.6.30` and I need `curl` extension. In `php.ini` I have

```
extension_dir = "ext"
...
extension=php_curl.dll
```

`ext` dir exists in folder where php is installed, and  `php_curl.dll` exists in either `ext` folder and in php install folder. `php -m` shows that `curl` is installed. Still the following code

```
curl_version();
```

outputs `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_version()`

The question is: how can I find out what's wrong with `curl`?

**UPD.** I'm using `Win7` and the server is `Apache 2.4`

Comment: Do you do checks on command line and run code on Apache?

Comment: Create a new page containing only: `<?php phpinfo();`. Browse to that page with your browser (through Apache). Do you see curl anywhere on that page?

Comment: `display_startup_errors=On` and restart apache.  check the error logs. there should be something about curl failing to load, and why

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes, there's `CURL`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `php --ini` says that PHP CLI uses the same .ini if that is what you are asking about

Comment: Have you checked your servers error log? It seems like curl have some dependencies that aren't always installed on Windows by default. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099174/php-and-curl-under-windows-7-64-bits-and-apache

Comment: @Eugeny89 But why verify things indirectly when you can just do a direct check? It's like trying to repair a broken watch through bevelled crystal.